# Наследование классов в С++ с использованием конструкторов и деструкторов

Tags: c++, наследование, конструктор, деструктор

Сделал лабораторную на тему наследования в С++ с использованием конструкторов и деструкторов.
Проблема в том, что мне выводит в консоль несколько раз информацию о классах.
Как это можно исправить и может еще есть какие-то ошибки?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class Animals
{
public:
float Size;
int Limbs;                     //кол-во конечностей
string Whence;                 //откуда
string Int_Color;              //основной цвет/окраска
bool Flies;
Animals() {cout << "\nAnimals created\n";

Size=1.8;
Limbs=4;                  
Whence="Africa";
Int_Color="gray";
Flies=false;
cout << "Size = " << Size << endl;
cout << "Limbs = " << Limbs << endl;
cout << "Whence = " << Whence << endl;
cout << "Int_Color = " << Int_Color << endl;
cout << "Flies = " << Flies << endl << endl;
}
~Animals() {cout << "Animals destroyed\n\n";}
};

class Birds : public Animals {
public:
bool Flies=true;             
bool Fly_away_in_winter;
Birds() {cout << "Birds created\n";

Size=0.9;
Limbs=4;                  
Whence="Russia,Spain,Czech Republic, Romania";
Int_Color="brown";
Flies=true;
Fly_away_in_winter=true;

cout << "Size = " << Size << endl;
cout << "Limbs = " << Limbs << endl;
cout << "Whence = " << Whence << endl;
cout << "Int_Color = " << Int_Color << endl;
cout << "Flies = " << Flies << endl;
cout << "Fly_away_in_winter = " << Fly_away_in_winter << endl << endl;  
}
~Birds() {cout << "Birds destroyed\n ";}
}; 

class Mammals : public Animals {             
public:
Mammals() {cout << "Mammals created\n";

Size=1,5;
Limbs=4;
Whence="Russia, Europe, China";
Int_Color="brown";
Flies=false;

cout << "Size = " << Size << endl;
cout << "Limbs = " << Limbs << endl;
cout << "Whence = " << Whence << endl;
cout << "Int_Color = " << Int_Color << endl;
cout << "Flies = " << Flies << endl;
    }
~Mammals() {cout << "Mammals destroyed\n ";}
 };

class Artiodactyls : public Mammals {      
public:
  Artiodactyls() {cout << "Artiodactyls created\n";

Size=6;
Limbs=4;
Whence="Africa";
Int_Color="Yellow";
Flies=false;

cout << "Size = " << Size << endl;
cout << "Limbs = " << Limbs << endl;
cout << "Whence = " << Whence << endl;
cout << "Int_Color = " << Int_Color << endl;
cout << "Flies = " << Flies << endl;
  }
  ~Artiodactyls() {cout << "Artiodactyls destroyed\n ";}
};


int main()
{
Animals Ringo;

Birds Eagle;

Mammals Brown_bear;

Artiodactyls Giraffe;

cout << "\n";
return 0;    

}
```

Comment: При создании производного класса вызывается конструктор базового, поэтому, например, создавая объект типа Artiodactyls вызываются конструкторы Animals -> Mammals -> Artiodactyls, деструкторы вызываются в обратном порядке

Comment: Так а почему вы решили, что это "проблема" и что это надо "исправлять"? Все работает так, как и должно работать. Также: `Size=1,5;` - это совсем не то, что вы пытались получить.

Comment: В программировании надо быть ленивым :)  В вашем коде в каждом классе повторяется фрагмент вывода информации о существе. Его надо написать ОДИН раз в функции базового класса, а вызывать одну строчку этой функции в конструкторах производного класса, а в базовом не вызывать вообще.  Следующий "уровень" будет в том, чтобы все эти "информполя" просто вставить в параметры конструктора базового класса, а в конструкторе производных вызвать конструктор базового с параметрами, сэкономится еще строчек 20 кода :)

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы прояснить себе этот момент, нужно понять как выделяется память под данный (к примеру) объект типа `Birds`. 
Если у этого класса есть родительский класс, то для его создания в первую очередь будет/будут вызваны конструкторы всех родительских классов от самого верхнего и по цепочке до того, который вы создаете.

Почему вам выводит информацию несколько раз? Потому что конструктор родительского класса вызывается `несколько` раз. В вашем случае:

- 4 раза конструктор `Animals`
- 1 раз `Birds`
- 2 раза `Mammals`
- 1 раз `Artiodactyls`

Цепочка деструкторов будет вызвана в обратном порядке. 
С декструкторами так же есть один нюанс, который касается оператора `virtual`. Это выходит за тему данного вопроса, по этому просто оставлю [ссылку](http://www.equestionanswers.com/cpp/virtual-destructor-inheritance.php).